# Load in multiple input files with for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, file-upload

I have multiple (264 to be precise) files with yearly precipitation, which are named 'precip1752.xlsx','precip1753.xlsx', ... 'precip2016.xlsx'. How can I load all these files at once with a for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the files are in a directory with name `dirName`.

```
D = dir([dirName '*.xlsx']);
for di = 1:length(D)
    filePath = fullfile(dirName, D(di).name);
    % insert code here to process file named filePath using xlsread
end
```

Use the `xlsread` function to read the data into MATLAB.